# Angular(4) router does not replace routes rather stacks them up when called from inside Google API load callback

Tags: javascript, angular, authentication, google-api, angular-router

I am trying to use Google Authentication in my Angular 4 app. I loaded Google platform.js and api.js in index.html. Now onClick login button I do

```
gapi.load('auth2', () => {
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
});
```

Now instead of replacing the previous route, Angular is stacking the new route over the old route (/login). I can see from web console that both my Login and Home components are present as below,

```
<app>
    <router-outlet><router-outlet>
    <home></home>
    <login></login>
</app>
```

Home is supposed to replace Login, but that didn't happen. Can anyone offer some help here?

Answer (score 0):

Gapi client library does not go well with Angular, I used Rest API calls instead. That solved the issue.